# How to insert multidimensional array into database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

My array i.e. $_SESSION['cart_array'] contains

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => qwerty [quantity] => 2 [unit_price] => 500 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => skjbm [quantity] => 3 [unit_price] => 100 ) )
```

The code to insert into my database code is

```
 foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item){ $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_added(id,ip_address,order_id,email,item_id,unit_price,quantity,total,pay_status)values('','','','','".$each_item['item_id']."','".$each_item['quantity']."','".$each_item['unit_price']."','','')");
 if(!mysql_query( $sql)){
    // maybe not the best use of `die` here?
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}echo "record added"; }
```

My problem is when I run the script it add only one item ie: item_id=qwerty,quantity=2 and unit_price=500 to the table where as I have two items in the `$_SESSION['cart_array']`.

And mysql error shows:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

How to enter two and multiple items into database?

Comment: try echoing your query before you execute it, to see what query is actually being built and executed.

also consider using pdo and prepared statements instead of concatenation. google sql injection

Comment: @pala please please rewrite the above code that how can i insert it into the database ....it will be great help....

Comment: it would be a great help if you'd echo the completed query string and then put it into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. Btw `mysql` is deprecated use `mysqli`

```
$insert_query = 'INSERT INTO product_added (id,ip_address,order_id,email,item_id,unit_price,quantity,total,pay_status) values ';

 foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item){ 

    $insert_query .= "('','','','','".$each_item['item_id']."','".$each_item['quantity']."','".$each_item['unit_price']."','',''),";        

 }

$query = rtrim($insert_query, ',');
if(!mysql_query($query)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}else{
    echo "record added";
}
```

Comment: you are guniess @Raja ...one more question if any person change the quantity in shopping cart in real time how can i update the only quantity value to database.as it was already stored in database that quatity is 2 if person set it to let say 5 how can i update  when person click on proceed to checkout

Comment: why you want to store to db before checkout.

Comment: hi @Raja ..u made my day for this thank a lot..i have an question..when user hit proceed the checkout button this session cart insert into database and user goes to login page..but if user back to prev cart page and delete one of the item and again hit proceed to checkout button it again insert into database and duplicate/double the data how to make security check wheather the cart item exist or any changes happen or any item deleted just update the cart or delete the specific item from the cart using sessioon orderid

Comment: when my cart has some products i bind it to a product id and both ll be store in session ie.$_session['cart_array'],and $_SESSION['orderid'].and when in real time user change the quantity in cart it update the stored session array quantity..tilll now its ok..and when hit checkout button goes to login page and session array stored in database with session orderid.and after when login email id ll be attach to the orderid ,,till now its ok...but in exception when user back to  cart page and again hit the proceed to checkout button

Comment: again the session array stored in database double time how can i check it...if user back and chage the quantity again and hit checkout how can i search the previous stored item with id and update the only quantity button...thank you @Raja